# Creating a Turbo Tax like Software

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have to develop a tool in visual Studio about a Chemical Analysis Tool kinda similar to Turbo Tax Software.This tool asks the user some questions about the chemical composition of the product and some production data during the run time.On the basis of the values entered by the user,it does some calculations(some Big calculations) on the back end and prints/pdfs a report which displays the total environmental impact of that product in terms of green house gases,waste,water consumption etc.

So,according to my research online,one way would be to store the data entered during run time in a database and then use Crystal Reports to generate a report.
Another thing I can do is to create some kind of Quiz engine which I still have to figure out how to do.

I am wondering if I am thinking in the right direction or there is some other way to do it. I will really appreciate any help on this one.

Software Used: Visual Studio 2010, C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:
Use MS Access for the backend and Crystal for the front end. Why Access?

1. Because you can easily develop your data entry forms (including drop-down boxes, data validation, questions that depend on answers to other questions, etc.)
2. You can query your data with standard SQL to do all your computations.
3. You can write your own nonstandard procedures.

Once Access is done with gathering the data and making the computations, you can output the results to a Crystal Report, an Excel file, or even use Access's Report forms (I don't recommend this, personally.  Not enough customization and too ugly for my tastes.)

(I'm going to make this question a Favorite. I want to see how other people answer it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.You mean I should temporarily store the data entered by the user in the database first and then generate a crystal report on it.?

Comment: the problem is that I have to do the computations on the data entered by user, I really don't know how am I gonna do that using access.

Comment: Exactly.  I regularly query our backend, store the results in a little Access db, and use that db as the source for a Crystal Report pdf.

Comment: Regarding your computations, Access also lets you write your own custom functions using Visual Basic for Applications. VBA may be old, but it is a full featured language that supports loops, arrays, etc. (Access 2000-2003 uses VBA, Access 2007+ uses VB.NET).  If you have specific questions on how to implement your computations, StackOverflow is a great place to get them answered.